# .htaccess file - forward everything, but not?

Tags: .htaccess

First time user, been looking all night. 
We recently changed our site from .net to wordpress. We transferred over half of the news articles and not the other half. So now we get old users coming to the site and getting a 404.

The news articles that exist in the wordpress site have been reditected and work fine, for example, 
www.example.com/news/transfered-news-story.aspx
redirects to
www.example.com/blog/news/transfered-news-story

this was done manually.

What I need help with is if someone comes to the site with any other request, e.g.
www.example.com/news/this-didnt-get-moved.aspx
or 
www,example.com/news/anything-else
or
www.example.com/news/2010/02

all just gets redirected to 
www.example.com/blog/news

I have been reading on and off for a couple of weeks and tried a few things but they all append the additional stuff on the end of the redirected string.

so www.example.com/news/my-stuff-ok
becomes www.example.com/blog/news/my-stuff-ok (and I want to drop the my-stuff-ok)

I hope you get what I'm after, any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks
Phil

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write a directive that converts a 404 to a url ([documentation](http://www.thesitewizard.com/archive/custom404.shtml)):

```
ErrorDocument 404 /blog/news
```

However, you really should go through the motions of adding manual redirects (permanent redirect) to the new url for each of the other articles because you will take a considerable SEO hit if those urls no longer serve up the content that was linked by the search engine.